# MSSQL procedure does not complete from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

**PHP:** 5.4.20 Windows
**Server**: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I am running into an issue where the following stored procedure does not run in its entirety when called from a PHP script (but it does run, with no errors returned):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main_procedure (@uid int)
AS  
BEGIN
  DECLARE @NOW DATETIME
  SET @NOW = getDate()

  DELETE FROM metrics WHERE uid = @uid AND timestamp < @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_a @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_b @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_c @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_d @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_e @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_f @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_g @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_h @uid, @NOW
  EXEC update_metric_i @uid, @NOW
END
```

The function is called via: "EXEC main_procedure 1234"  where 1234 is a user ID to pass to the individual update_metric functions. Each individual update_metric_n procedure adds a record for each metric, then parses through the past 12 months to populate the row with a month-over-month breakdown.

**When called from Microsoft SQL Management Studio, the procedure executes all steps correctly.**

**When called from PHP, it runs all but the last procedure.**

The others all run correctly, but for some reason the last one doesn't run. Re-ordering the procedures confirms that the issue is not an error in the last procedure as it runs fine when moved to the top of the list.

Here's my PHP that executes the procedure:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=######; Database=#####;", $user, $pass);
$conn->prepare("EXEC main_procedure ?");
$conn->execute(array("1234"));
```

Any thoughts on why this would stop after the eighth procedure, but only when executed via PHP?

Comment: PHP would have no knowledge of what's going on inside the server. It won't tell mssql "Hey, this stored proc? Do everything exceptr the metric_i line". PHP can't possibly know what's going on in the sproc. It just sends over the string `EXEC ... ?` and waits for a response.

Comment: That's what I thought, but consistently, the last procedure fails to run when called through PHP but runs flawlessly when executed directly from MSSMS. This is baffling me. I was hoping someone with internal knowledge of SQL or PHP/PDO would know what might cause this? Strangely enough, It doesn't return any errors. It just omits one of the procedures.

Comment: are you using the same credentials in php as your in mssms?  what happens if you try running the individual exec's separately from php? perhaps the last one has some different perms that the account php is using  isn't permitted to access.

Comment: Not initially, but I changed the script to run as the same user I use in MSSMS and it did the same thing. One thing I'm considering is rewriting the individual procedures to use straight SQL rather than cursors. Not sure if that will make any difference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, not significantly different but worth a try.

Not sure if this is an typo but `execute()` method is available only on the statement objects, which is returned by `prepare()`.

```
try {
    $conn= new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=######; Database=#####;", $user, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("EXEC dbo.main_procedure @uid = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array("1234"));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'PDO failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I omitted $stmt = .... and it should have read like your code. I made this change and saw an error stating "The active result for the query contains no fields". Looking this up, it appears that SET NOCOUNT ON should resolve this. In my case, it didn't resolve the error, but the procedure does run in its entirety. (I wonder if I need it in all the subprocedures too)